# Is dataadapter. Update prone to SQL injection?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is the Code below prone to sql injection. AS far i know CommandBuilder always uses parameterized queries when generating it's SELECT / UPDATE / INSERT commands.

```
using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand))
using (var cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter))
{
cmdBuilder.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;

using (var dataset = new DataSet())
{


dataAdapter.UpdateBatchSize = 0;
dataAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;
dataAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false;

stopwatch.Start();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataset, "ABC");
dataset.AcceptChanges();
ds.tables[0].Rows["ABC"] = MALICIOUS SQL INJECTION ATTEMPT; // let's
say this is where the end user could slip malicious string he wanted
into


dataAdapter.Update(dataset, " ABC");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CommandBuilders use parameterized queries when generating insert, update, and delete statements. So no, you will not be subject to a SQL injection attack from them. In a parameterized query, the SQL statement with its parameter markers are parsed and then the parameters are pushed separately. Values inside the parameters are not parsed by the SQL query parser, so there is nowhere in the code path for an injection to occur.

Another option to consider is to use an ORM (object relational mapper) like Entity Framework or something lighter like Dapper.